# As Rome began to decline is there any contemporary accounts from time as to the cause?

Tags: ancient-history, ancient-rome

I guess fall of Rome seems amazing to me in that they had things we recognise in modern states

Militia, ability to buy property with paper rather than gold and manufacturing.

As decline began as there any contemporary sources warning the empire that they risked loosing it all?

Comment: Only since at least Cicero - so nothing new there.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Did ancient Romans anticipate the fall of Rome?](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/52539/did-ancient-romans-anticipate-the-fall-of-rome)