# Leading up to ‘fall’ of western Roman Empire did advanced quarrying engineering stop or gradually fade?

Tags: ancient-rome, early-medieval

I know Roman Empire didn’t suddenly disappear it was more gradual.

Romans used advanced techniques to build their fantastic buildings.

I guess to expand on my question I've seen examples of advanced column cutting and boring granite that even with modern tools are hard to do.

Wider than that though you’d need surveyors and other experts to do this.

Did the loss of skills start inline with the empires decline and are there historical texts outlining this?

E.g., in the modern era, it’s common to say they don’t ‘build it like that anymore’ or ‘we just don’t have the skills nowadays’.

Did the Romans start recognising falling standards? I.e. call out say where roads were in disrepair, etc.?

Comment: Remember that the fall of Rome was not the end of the Roman Empire or culture: Constantinople stood up for almost a millenia. The Hagia Sophia and lots of other constructions attest to that.

Comment: Thanks yes have specified more in terms of western empire !

Comment: Some Roman chronicles of the times did lament the general decline, but the focus was mostly on military misfortunes, loss of life and liberty. See some examples in the answers given [here](https://history.stackexchange.com/questions/52539/did-ancient-romans-anticipate-the-fall-of-rome/).

Comment: In regards to the "modern tools" bit, a lot of what's been lost is "cheap skilled labor".  In the Roman Empire, you could afford to have a stonemason tapping away at a column segment for a few days to get the fluting *just* right.  Today, not so much.